# PDF Uploads with Paperclip still shows missing.png

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I've searched for about an hour on this and couldn't find an answer so maybe someone here can help. I have pdf uploads enabled for my model, but when I link to it in my view, even if the record doesn't have a pdf in it it still links to missing.png. I'd like it to return nil if there's no pdf so I can just do link_to_unless. I tried setting :default_url to a blank string but I guess that doesn't count as nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= link_to 'Resume', page.upload(:original) %>
```

Didn't know about the :original part.

Comment: I know this is old, but could you specify which part of the code are a result of your model names and which parts are paperclip keywords

Comment: page is my model, .upload(:original) is paperclip